# What happened to System.Data.SQLite 1.0.91.0?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, system.data.sqlite

I distinctly remember having System.Data.SQLite 1.0.91.0 installed. However, now that I look for it, it is gone. Nada. Doesn't exists.

Does anyone have a backup/reason why it was pulled?

Comment: [Here](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/news.wiki) it says "release scheduled". Maybe you had a pre-release?

Comment: @Gert maybe. I cant find it anymore though.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's been released again:
http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/news.wiki

Answer (score -1):

I think you must mean 1.0.90 instead:

http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/news.wiki

Comment: Dang, crap. That sucks.